# How can i see an individual cluster latency?

Tags: cassandra, cql

How can i see an individual cluster latency, number of node up/down, rea/write performance of a cluster in cassandra? Does cassandra stores all these information somewere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking at the nodetool utility for this information.

```
nodetool ring
```

will give you the up/down status of the cluster and

```
nodetool tablehistograms
```

will give you table read/write latencies. Nodetool has many other commands for looking at the cluster or node internals.

There is a lot of information about it [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsNodetool.html).

Comment: All these information for a speific node only. How can get info for a cluster. e.g read/write, disk space for a cluster not just for a node?